# How can I find expected target phrase or keywords from given sentence in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, feature-extraction, spacy

I am wondering that is there any efficient way to extract expected target phrase or key phrase from given sentence. So far I tokenized the given sentence and get POS tag for each word. Now I am not sure how to extract target key phrase or keyword from given sentence. The way of doing this is not intuitive to me.

Here is my input sentence list:

```
sentence_List= {"Obviously one of the most important features of any computer is the human interface.", "Good for everyday computing and web browsing.",
"My problem was with DELL Customer Service", "I play a lot of casual games online[comma] and the touchpad is very responsive"}
```

here is the tokenized sentence:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(i) for i in sentence_List]
tokenized=[i for i in tokenized_sents]
```

Here I used `Spacy` to get POS tag of words:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

res=[]
for i in range(len(sentence_list.index)):
    for token in i:
        res.append(token.pos_)
```

so I may use `NER` (a.k.a, name entity relation) from `spacy` but its output is not the same thing with my pre-defined expected target phrase. Does anyone know how to accomplish this task either using `Spacy` or `stanfordcorenlp` module in python? what is an efficient solution to make this happen? Any idea? Thanks in advance :)

**desired output**:

I want to get the list of target phrase from respective sentence list as follow:

```
target_phraseList={"human interface","everyday computing","DELL Customer Service","touchpad"}
```

so I concatenate my input `sentence_list` with an expected target phrase, my final desired output would be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.Series(sentence_List, target_phraseList)
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

How can I get my expected target phrases from a given input sentence list by using `spacy`? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly do this using spacy by [Phrase Matcher](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher).

```
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('DELL', None, nlp(u"DELL Customer Service"))
doc = nlp(u"My problem was with DELL Customer Service")
matches = matcher(doc)
```

Comment: would it be possible to make your code smarter? Because I picked up target phrase by reading it, but how python get that phrase by using input sentence list? Any more thoughts? Is that possible to make this code line `matcher.add('DELL', None, nlp(u"DELL Customer Service"))` smarter for applying all sentences? Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by making the code smarter? An example?